# update message " Your search returned no results. " when no records found

Tags: magento2, phtml, catalogsearch, messages

I wanted to update message "

> Your search returned no results

. " in magento2.But i am not getting directory file to change the message.I am new to magento2. Please let me know the exact file path for this message.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2):

You can override this vendor file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml

here in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/result.phtml

and you can change that text there.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks for reply. But this file is not present in 

    app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/result.phtml. this location.

Comment: that file is not available but you have to copy your vendor directories file there and you can change that text. Please check this file first.. **vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml**

Comment: Let me know still you need any help then.

Comment: thanks. i have done..And got result what i want.

Comment: Hi Kishan ,I need one more help. when i do catalog search with 2 char length.it gives me exception error.while i have set catalog serach>min query length is 3.if i set 1 then everything is fine. But in other site i have set 3.and serach with 2 charcter then it gives me message no record found.Not giving me error.